# Can't change Windows Docker storage location (The parameter is incorrect)

Tags: docker, windows

I'm trying to move the Docker storage location to another drive. This is my configuration file:

```json
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": false,
  "experimental": false,
  "data-root": "E:\\test"
}
```

I also tried to use `"graph"` instead of `data-root` (probably that was they to do it in the older versions) without any luck. I also gave read/write permissions to `Everyone` just in case. After restarting the daemon, I see the Docker directories and files are created in that folder, however when I try to pull the image, I'm getting following error:

> Executing task: docker build --pull --rm -f "Docker\BuildTools\Dockerfile" -t msbuildssdt "Docker\BuildTools" <
> Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB Error response from
> daemon: chtimes \?\E:\test\tmp\docker-builder614293845\coverage: The
> parameter is incorrect. The terminal process
> "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command
> docker build --pull --rm -f "Docker\BuildTools\Dockerfile" -t
> msbuildssdt "Docker\BuildTools"" terminated with exit code: 1.

It's working well if I change the `data-root` value to any folder located on the `C:` drive.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the `E:` drive was formatted with `exFAT` partition. After I formatted it to `NTFS` it started to work.